# How to sort pairs of points so that they connect?

Tags: ruby, geometry

I have an Array of pairs of Vectors that are all edges in a clockwise path around a polygon. The problem is, they're not in the right order. I would like to sort them so that the start and end of the Array are the same Vector, and each individual point overlaps (endpoint-to-startpoint):

```
require 'matrix'
unsorted_points = [[Vector[-5, 0], Vector[-3, 2]], 
                   [Vector[-3, 2], Vector[3, 2]], 
                   [Vector[-3, -2], Vector[-5, 0]], 
                   [Vector[3, 2], Vector[5, 0]], 
                   [Vector[3, -2], Vector[-3, -2]], 
                   [Vector[5, 0], Vector[3, -2]]]

sorted_points = [[Vector[-5, 0], Vector[-3, 2]], 
                 [Vector[-3, 2], Vector[3, 2]],
                 [Vector[3, 2], Vector[5, 0]],
                 [Vector[5, 0], Vector[3, -2]],
                 [Vector[3, -2], Vector[-3, -2]],
                 [Vector[-3, -2], Vector[-5, 0]]]
```

What's the most Ruby-idiomatic way to do this?

edit: Vectors are objects from the 'matrix' library, but they can be indexed just like arrays, e.g. `unsorted_points[0][0][0]` is `-5`.

Comment: You need to tell us what `Vector` is, particularly how to extract the coordinates from them.

Comment: @sawa [`Vector`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html) is in the Ruby stdlib; seems reasonable for an question to assume we know that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First turn the original point pair array into a map with the first point the key, and the second the value:

```
ptsMap = Hash[ * unsorted_points.flatten(1) ]

=> {Vector[-5, 0]  => Vector[-3, 2],
    Vector[-3, 2]  => Vector[3, 2],
    Vector[-3, -2] => Vector[-5, 0],
    Vector[3, 2]   => Vector[5, 0],
    Vector[3, -2]  => Vector[-3, -2],
    Vector[5, 0]   => Vector[3, -2] }
```

Then start with the first point pair and chain from second point to the first via the map (I'd note your array doesn't contain "points" it contains edges between two points):

```
ordered_edges = (1...unsorted_points.size).inject ( [unsorted_points.first] ) do |acc,_|
  nextPt = acc.last[1]
  acc << [ nextPt, ptsMap[nextPt] ]
end

=> [[Vector[-5, 0],  Vector[-3, 2]],
    [Vector[-3, 2],  Vector[3, 2]],
    [Vector[3, 2],   Vector[5, 0]],
    [Vector[5, 0],   Vector[3, -2]],
    [Vector[3, -2],  Vector[-3, -2]],
    [Vector[-3, -2], Vector[-5, 0]] ]
```

Note that points are not strictly comparable in this context, so there is no total ordering (as required for a simple `sort`. Each of your point pairs describes an edge which supplies a partial ordering.  The above finds a candidate total ordering assuming the first edge's head is the first point you want.

This technique will fail if the original list doesn't actually describe a set of discrete connected points. You might get more robust results using [topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). Ruby has a library for this: [TSort](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/tsort/rdoc/TSort.html). With this you could detect when your original set of edges are not a single strongly connected component.

Answer (score 0):

[Edit: I originally presented two ways of doing it, one using sort, the other recursion.  @dbenhur showed that no `sort` would work because there was not a complete ordering of the elements of the array.  I've therefore deleted that approach.  For the record, the heart of my misguided sort was:

```
 unsorted.sort {|v1,v2| (v1 == first || v1[1]==v2[0]) ? -1 : 1}
```

The second approach was the use of recursion.  Upon reflection, it way obvious I could do the same thing in a simple loop, which follows.]

```
sorted = [unsorted_points.shift]
until unsorted_points.empty?
  node = sorted[-1][1]
  target = unsorted_points.find {|e| e[0] == node}
  sorted << unsorted_points.delete(target)
end
sorted
  # => [[Vector[-5,  0], Vector[-3,  2]],
        [Vector[-3,  2], Vector[ 3,  2]],
        [Vector[ 3,  2], Vector[ 5,  0]],
        [Vector[ 5,  0], Vector[ 3, -2]],
        [Vector[ 3, -2], Vector[-3, -2]],
        [Vector[-3, -2], Vector[-5,  0]]]
```

Comment: I don't think you can actually make a `<=>` that will make `sort` work in the general case.  It accidentally works on the OPs original ordering, but there are other initial orderings on which it fails (eg: `[[Vector[5, 0], Vector[3, -2]], [Vector[-3, 2], Vector[3, 2]], [Vector[-5, 0], Vector[-3, 2]], [Vector[3, 2], Vector[5, 0]], [Vector[3, -2], Vector[-3, -2]], [Vector[-3, -2], Vector[-5, 0]]]`)

Comment: When I applied `sort` to the array in your comment, I obtained the following ('Vector' not shown): `[ [[5, 0], [3, -2]], [[3, -2], [-3, -2]], [[-3, -2], [-5, 0]], [[-5, 0], [-3, 2]], [[-3, 2], [3, 2]], [[3, 2], [5, 0]] ]`.  Is that not correct?

Comment: @dbenhur, you may be right about `@sort` not working because we don't have a complete ordering.  I'd like to think about that. I assume `@sort` terminates when all consecutive pairs satisfy the ordering.

Comment: In ruby 2.0.0p195, `[[Vector[5, 0], Vector[3, -2]], [Vector[-3, 2], Vector[3, 2]], [Vector[-5, 0], Vector[-3, 2]], [Vector[3, 2], Vector[5, 0]], [Vector[3, -2], Vector[-3, -2]], [Vector[-3, -2], Vector[-5, 0]]].sort {|v1,v2| (v1 == first || v1[1]==v2[0]) ? -1 : 1}` produces `[[Vector[-5, 0], Vector[-3, 2]], [Vector[-3, 2], Vector[3, 2]], [Vector[-3, -2], Vector[-5, 0]], [Vector[3, 2], Vector[5, 0]], [Vector[5, 0], Vector[3, -2]], [Vector[3, -2], Vector[-3, -2]]]`

Comment: `Array#sort` [calls](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c#L2441) [`ruby_qsort`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/util.c#L304-L452). [Quick sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) is a divide and conquer algorithm that divides an array into sub-arrays above and below a selected pivot, then recurses into each subarray. It terminates when it's descended to partitions of singleton elements.

Comment: BTW, The complexity of sort is O(NlogN) (or worse for degenerate quicksort cases). Your recursive/loop method is O(N^2) (because `find` in the inner loop is O(N)). The method I proposed first builds a map in O(N) time, then iterates once using the O(1) lookups on the map, so its overall runtime complexity is O(N). This could have significant impact on efficiency for larger edge lists.